# what does '</' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I use Aptana Studio to code JavaScript.

When I write string with `</`, there will be warning saying

**'<' + '/' + letter not allowed here**

But it does not trigger error in browsers.

what does `</` mean in JavaScript?

Comment: Same thing it does in SGML/HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inline scripts (e.g, using `<script>`), some HTML parsers may interpret anything that looks like `</this` (especially `</script>`) as an HTML tag, rather than part of your source code. Your IDE is trying to keep you from typing this by mistake.

This means that, if you're using an inline script, you can't have a `</tag>` as a constant string in JavaScript:

```
var endTag = "</tag>"; // don't do this!
```

You'll need to break it up somehow to keep it from being interpreted as a tag:

```
var endTag = "<" + "/tag>";
```

Note that this only applies to inline scripts. Standalone scripts (e.g, a `.js` file) can have anything they want in them.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything in a string, outside of a string it would be a syntax error.

EDIT: Before someone nitpicks there are some exceptions, eg `var i = 1 </* comment */ 2;` is legal and there may be some other cases (like performing less-than operation on a regex) but generally speaking it signifies nothing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's your IDE is denying it. Aptana Studio may be assuming some sort of injection attack, and thus throws an error.

You would probably get a more direct answer by asking them directly though; a general program help site like StackOverflow is less likely to know the reasoning for specific cases such as this.